# How does @State property doesn't save the state?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am new to iOS. I am trying to do some test UI in order to understand some basic things here, my question is - there are two buttons on my screen

```
...
  @State private var isAlertVisible: Bool = false

...

      Button("1") {
        isAlertVisible = true
      }
      .alert(isPresented: $isAlertVisible, content: {
        return Alert(title: Text("Hello there!"), message: Text("This is my first pop-up"), dismissButton: .default(Text("Awesome!")))
      })
      Button("2") {
      }
      .alert(isPresented: $isAlertVisible, content: {
        return Alert(title: Text("Who's There?"), message: Text("Little old lady."), dismissButton: .default(Text("Little old lady who?")))
      })
...
```

Test scenario is :

1. Click on the btn 2  - nothing happen
2. Click on the btn 1 - opens pop-up and `isAlertVisible` value is now `==true`
3. Click again on the btn 2 - opens the pop-up as `isAlertVisible` value is now `==true`

But the actual result is that click on button 2 is ignored and in the debug I see that the `isAlertVisible` value is still false.

The question is - why after the click on the btn 1 state of `isAlertVisible` didn't change to true?

***UPD***

I would like perfrase the question like this

...
@State private var isAlertVisible: Bool = false

...

```
  Button("1") {
    isAlertVisible = true
  }
  .alert(isPresented: $isAlertVisible, content: {
    return Alert(title: Text("Hello there!"), message: Text("This is my first pop-up"), dismissButton: .default(Text("Awesome!")))
  })
```

let's say I have one btn and the first time I click it, so I set debug(in order to see the value) and I expect that after I the first click `isAlertVisible` is true, but when I make the second click in debugger I see that value is still false. Looks like it somehow after the click returns the value from true to the default state that is false... Could it be possible?

Comment: You need to variables. One for the first alert and one for the second each button triggers a different alert. Button 2 has an empty action right now. They are probably sharing a container like a list row and that is why it works the second time.

Comment: Does this your answere? https://stackoverflow.com/a/67265716/14733292

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: Yes that is possible because like @alex-b wrote, you bound your `isAlertVisible` to the `isPresented` behaviour of the alert. So when you click alert away, the alert is no longer presented and it sets `isAlertVisible` back to false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your code is not complete for example your Button 2 does not have an action.

Second, if you want to show two different alert you should use two different variables to present them.

Third, to explain why your value is false after the second button click. The alert modifier takes in a Binding to decide if the alert should be presented or not. This is a two way binding meaning it changes the state in your code but also in the Alert View created from the system. If you click on the dismiss button of the alert it changes the value of your variable back two false to represent the state correctly.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: got it, two-way binding is the thing that I missed, right.